# nsimplify's tolerance doesn't work as intended in symbolic expressions

Tags: python, math, sympy

I have been working on simplifying a Matrix, which is relatively large and contains many symbolic constants.

The main purpose is to nullify terms that multiply  symbolic constants and are lower than a specific tolerance. The main problem that I have is represented here: (it also represents a part of Matrix I work on)

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
AA         = sp.Symbol('m')
TestMatrix = Matrix([[0, 0, 0, 0, -143733*AA/15544162865157868, 0, -3793535*AA/205216068200524458, 1091672/883397, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -72121*AA/59733839071490146, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
sp.nsimplify(TestMatrix[0,4],tolerance=1e-6,rational=True)
sp.nsimplify(TestMatrix[0,4]/AA,tolerance=1e-6,rational=True)
```

the above 2 commands return `TestMatrix[0,4],TestMatrix[0,4]/AA`

while the

```
sp.nsimplify(np.float(TestMatrix[0,4]/AA),tolerance=1e-6,rational=True)
```

returns `0`

Note that in main matrix I have many symbols (and expressions like `10**-10*a*b*x` )in some elements, so 'floating' all coefficients from every symbol and combination of it would not be ideal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It think you are misunderstanding `tolerance` which is used to select how close a number has to be to a simpler form to be changed to that form. e.g.

```
>>> nsimplify(3.14,[pi])
157/50
>>> nsimplify(3.14,[pi],tolerance=.01)
pi
```

If you wish to set numbers smaller than a given threshold to zero, use `replace`:

```
>>> (y - 1e-7*x).replace(lambda x: x.is_Number and abs(x) < 1e-6, lambda x: 0)
y
```

Note, however, that when numbers are being multiplied by unknown values (symbols) and those symbols are replaced with large numbers the product may be large...so this sort of simplification is not recommended. But in the spirit of unix I have now shown you how to "shoot yourself in the foot." :-)

Comment: Sadly this is not working because `type(TestMatrix[0,4])` gives `sympy.core.mul.Mul` so it's not basically float. If it was float, nsimplify works as well

Comment: Try again with the modified answer. I thought you were dealing with Floats but you are dealing with Rationals. Either case can be handled with the `is_Number` test.